# Finding the pressure in vacuum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

I have the following question

[image]

And I have the formula for finding the pressure difference which is as follows:
$$P(below) = P(above) + ρgh  $$
And since they provide the information that it is vacuum, then Patm > Pabs.

Here is the solution:
[image]

I don't really understand why it is minus ρgh and I'm confused how to use the fact that it is vacuum. Also, what can we usually consider P(below) and P(above)?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the question is confusing because there is no vacuum here.

The minus sign is because the pressure in the pipe + the pressure due to 3cm of liquid = atmospheric pressure. The pressure in the pipe is *below* atmospheric pressure.

The pressure relative to atmospheric pressure is called gauge pressure. So the gauge pressure is $-\rho g h$. Pressure relative to zero is absolute pressure, $P_0-\rho gh$.

In this case $P(below)$ is the pressure at the lower side of the manometer, ie atmopheric pressure $P_0$. $P(above)$ is the pressure on the higher side of the manometer, ie the pressure in the pipe.

Comment: but what if you don't have a drawing, how would you assume what is the lower side of the manometer and what is the higher side?